# duplicity gpg error

Tags: backup, gnupg, deja-dup, duplicity

I have been using deja dup for backup for years now on this same computer. I recently upgraded my external hard drives that I use for backup, but successfully started doing incremental backups. After about a month of backing up, it seems the whole backup (years worth of it) is broken. It repeatedly asks for password when trying to backup or restore, and doesn't get anywhere. Here is the output I get when I set DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1

```
DUPLICITY: NOTICE 1
DUPLICITY: . Last full backup date: Fri Aug  4 16:23:38 2017

DUPLICITY: INFO 3 
DUPLICITY: backend BackendWrapper
DUPLICITY: archive-dir (() /home/irh/.cache/deja-dup/9d20ffe28417a8426debcb7928a93ab1 dir)
DUPLICITY: chain-complete
DUPLICITY:  full 20170804T202338Z 5588 enc
DUPLICITY: orphaned-sets-num 0
DUPLICITY: incomplete-sets-num 0
DUPLICITY: . Collection Status
DUPLICITY: . -----------------
DUPLICITY: . Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper
DUPLICITY: . Archive dir: /home/***/.cache/deja-dup/9d20ffe28417a8426debcb7928a93ab1
DUPLICITY: . 
DUPLICITY: . Found 0 secondary backup chains.
DUPLICITY: . 
DUPLICITY: . Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:
DUPLICITY: . -------------------------
DUPLICITY: . Chain start time: Fri Aug  4 16:23:38 2017
DUPLICITY: . Chain end time: Fri Aug  4 16:23:38 2017
DUPLICITY: . Number of contained backup sets: 1
DUPLICITY: . Total number of contained volumes: 5588
DUPLICITY: .  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
DUPLICITY: .                 Full         Fri Aug  4 16:23:38 2017              5588
DUPLICITY: . -------------------------
DUPLICITY: . No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Registering (mktemp) temporary file /tmp/duplicity-lNQEKG-tempdir/mktemp-k_KxTN-2

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Releasing lockfile /home/***/.cache/deja-dup/9d20ffe28417a8426debcb7928a93ab1/lockfile.lock

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Removing still remembered temporary file /tmp/duplicity-lNQEKG-tempdir/mktemp-k_KxTN-2

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Removing still remembered temporary file /tmp/duplicity-lNQEKG-tempdir/mkstemp-owcdRG-1

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . GPG error detail: Traceback (most recent call last):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1532, in <module>
DUPLICITY: .     with_tempdir(main)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1526, in with_tempdir
DUPLICITY: .     fn()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1380, in main
DUPLICITY: .     do_backup(action)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1507, in do_backup
DUPLICITY: .     check_last_manifest(col_stats)  # not needed for full backup
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1211, in check_last_manifest
DUPLICITY: .     last_backup_set.check_manifests()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 201, in check_manifests
DUPLICITY: .     remote_manifest = self.get_remote_manifest()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 235, in get_remote_manifest
DUPLICITY: .     manifest_buffer = self.backend.get_data(self.remote_manifest_name)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 694, in get_data
DUPLICITY: .     assert not fin.close()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_temp.py", line 226, in close
DUPLICITY: .     assert not self.fileobj.close()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 259, in close
DUPLICITY: .     self.gpg_failed()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 226, in gpg_failed
DUPLICITY: .     raise GPGError(msg)
DUPLICITY: . GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
DUPLICITY: . ===== Begin GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . gpg: AES encrypted data
DUPLICITY: . gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
DUPLICITY: . gpg: decryption failed: bad key
DUPLICITY: . ===== End GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . 
DUPLICITY: . 

DUPLICITY: ERROR 31 GPGError
DUPLICITY: . GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
DUPLICITY: . ===== Begin GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . gpg: AES encrypted data
DUPLICITY: . gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
DUPLICITY: . gpg: decryption failed: bad key
DUPLICITY: . ===== End GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: .
```

Is my only option to simply start backups fresh? I feel this is unacceptable since if this is possible to happen again, I won't be able to restore anything. I know my passphrase is correct, as it was never changed and is stored in both my memory and my keychain (and I have entered it manually many times now to no avail). Is their a more reliable backup solution than duplicity? Am I wasting time encrypting my backups? Thanks for your help, I am rather frustrated.

UPDATE: Just started new backup from scratch. Oh well.